# C - place integer in a char array and extract it

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

String manipulation in C is the bane of my existence, I have tried to understand how to manipulate char arrays and fall short of grasping it every time. I simply want to do this in C.

```
Method1 passes ["1298","9"]
Method2 receives and converts them both to ints

int method1(){
  char *values[2];
  int i = 1298;
  int j = 9;

  //sprintf(values,"%d" "%d",i,j);
  sprintf(&values[0],"%d" ,i);
  sprintf(&values[1],"%d" ,j);
  method2(values,2);
}
int method2(char *strings, int num_values){
   int i, j;
   char buffer[256];
   sscanf(buffer, "%d" "%d", &i, &j);
   printf("i: %d, j: %d\n",i,j);
   return 0;
}
```

The result of this is 1 and 9; but i want 1298 and 9
Please even after providing an answer, can you explain why it is the way it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    char *values[2];
```

The above line is parsed as `char *(values[2]);`, i.e., `[]` take precedence over `*`.  This means that `values` is an array with 2 elements.  The type of the elements is `char *`.  So, `values[0]` and `values[1]` are of type `char *`.  Since you haven't initialized the array elements, the two items in the array have unknown, random values.

```
    //sprintf(values,"%d" "%d",i,j);
```

Although you have commented this out, it seems like you were trying to store the string representation of `i` and `j` into `values` using one `sprintf` call.  As you probably found out, this is impossible.

```
    sprintf(&values[0],"%d" ,i);
```

Here, you are calling `sprintf` to store the string representation of `i` into the memory location pointed to by `values[0]`.  But as noted above, `values[0]` is not pointing anywhere useful, since you haven't initialized it.  This is bad.

```
    sprintf(&values[1],"%d" ,j);
```

Same as above.

```
    method2(values, 2);
```

Here, you are calling `method2`, but you haven't declared the signature of `method2`.  As it turns out, `method2` takes a `char *` and an int.  You are passing `values` and `2`.  `values` is an array of `char *`, which gets converted to a pointer in this context, so `method2` should take a `char **` and an `int`.

```
int method2(char *strings, int num_values){
```

This should be: `int method2(char **strings, int num_values) {`

```
    int i, j;
    char buffer[256];
    sscanf(buffer, "%d" "%d", &i, &j);
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here.  You are ignoring `strings`, but instead using a `buffer` variable.  `buffer` is uninitialized, so trying to interpret the data in it as two integers is pointless.

I am assuming you are writing this program to understand strings, pointers, and functions.  As such, there is no single correct way to do what you are trying to do.  But here is one approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Define method2 before method1, so that its definition is visible
   in method1 */

/* Assume that method2 will be called with one char * containing two integer
   values.  I also changed the return type to void since you weren't really
   using the int return value.  Same for method1. */
void method2(const char *strings)
{
    int i, j;
    sscanf(strings, "%d %d", &i, &j);
    printf("i: %d, j: %d\n",i,j);
}

void method1(void)
{
    /* Changed values to a char array that has enough space */
    char values[256];
    int i = 1298;
    int j = 9;

    sprintf(values, "%d %d", i, j);
    method2(values);
}

int main(void)
{
    method1();
    return 0;
}
```

The above outputs:

```
i: 1298, j: 9
```

There are a lot of moving parts in your program.  I recommend that you learn the basics about pointers, arrays etc., in C, before passing them around in functions.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your program is called **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**. You MUST use compiler warnings if you are learning.

Your code has many issues, you should READ about strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c) instead of trying stuff just to see if they work.

1. You are using `sprintf()` wrong, you should pass a pointer to `char` as the first parameter, that points to valid data. You are passing uninitialized pointers instead which leads to *undefined behavior*.
2. Function `method1()` (*please note, that methods are for classes or objects, in [c](/questions/tagged/c) there are no methods, just functions*) is also not passing anything anywhere. The array of pointer `values` is local to the function and is not accessible from outside the function. To **pass** something to a function you should do it through the parameters instead and it would be the other way around since you can't call `main()` from a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program because it is undefined behavior.
3. You are using `sscanf()` where you apparently what `fscanf()` or just `scanf()`.

   If you want to read input from the user use

   ```
   if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2)
       printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", i, j);
   else
       printf("Invalid input\n");
   ```

   you can substitute `scanf()` with `fscanf(stdin, ...` or another `FILE *` object to read from a  file.

   In your code, your program is expecting `buffer` to contain a string (*a sequence of bytes terminated with a `'\0'`*). You are passing an uninitialized array instead which invokes *undefined behavior*.

   If you want to test how `sscanf()` works, do this

   ```
   char buffer[] = "1 2";
   if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &i, &j) ...
   ```

   the rest is the same.

I would say, that you want this

```
int
main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int i;
    int j;

    sprintf(buffer, "%d %d", 1289, 9); // - This is not necessay, but for illustration
                                       // - This is also, unsafe as it could cause
                                       //   a buffer overflow.
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &i, &j) == 2) // Would be surprised if this is false,
        printf("values: %d %d\n", i, j);      // but you MUST always check to make 
    else                                      // sure, because this kind of situation
        printf("invalid input?\n");           // is very unusual in real code.

}
```

I hope you can see, why your code is SO wrong. You can also move the part you want to the function. But it should be the right part.

Comment: but in this case i am not getting user input, I have the values, how do i place them in the array to correctly extract them by the receiving method?

Comment: @i_use_the_internet Your code is too wrong so you should delete it, read about [tag:c] programming and start over.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I wrote up quickly; you can pass an array of strings to this function along with it's length and it will dynamically allocate an array of integers with their converted values.

The pitfall here is that with `strtol`: if it fails to convert one of the strings it will default to 0. So if an element in your array of strings happens to contain some non-numeric characters you may not get what you expect; and an error won't be reported as you'd have to also confirm that the string itself wasn't 0.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *convert_to_int_array(const char **strings, size_t length) {
    int *numbers = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    size_t i = 0;

    if(numbers == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = strtol(strings[i], NULL, 10);
    }
    return numbers;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *strings[2];
    strings[0] = "100";
    strings[1] = "50";
    int *numbers;
    size_t length = 2, i;

    numbers = convert_to_int_array(strings, length);
    if(numbers == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize numbers\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I use `fprintf` to show a way of handling errors; people typically don't like answers that ignore errors. And as for my coding style it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: I don't think that's bad. A programmer should NEVER ignore errors. But your answer is way too advanced for the level of the OP. You should put yourself in his situation, and notice that he doesn't even understand how to use `sprintf()`. If so, how would your answer help him? Your coding style is relevant for me, not for the question.

Comment: Now, it's worse. Why do you think there is a second parameter to `strtol()`?

Comment: @iharob According to the man page for `strtol`; the second argument can be NULL so long as it's NULL terminated; which happens to be the case for C-strings. And OP's example didn't include a string which has many integers; that'd be a different answer.

Comment: No, you're wrong. You are saying that there a pitfall, you can fix it with that second argument. It sotres a pointer to the *unconverted* characters. Read tha man page carefully. You think that because it can be `NULL` it SHOULD be `NULL`.?

Comment: I'm aware; I could additionally check that the end pointer is set to the end of that current string and then verify for sure if there was an error. But I didn't have time at the instance to account for that so I just noted it in my answer. If OP chooses to implement it; then they may fix my pitfall.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`char values[10];
  int i = 1298;
  int j = 9;
  sprintf(values,"%d %d",i,j);`